# Missing Beta Badges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, user-accounts

A couple days ago somebody [mentioned](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/417832#417832) the [Beta Badge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta), which is given to users who "actively participated in the private beta". If you view [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399), it defines "active participation" as "...earning at least three bronze badges". Yet, on the page that lists [the users who have the Beta Badge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta), there are a couple who have only two badges besides the Beta Badge, while people who earned more than three or more badges during the private beta aren't listed there.

I (and others) met that requirement before the public beta, yet we aren't classified as people who participated in the beta.  I know that badges and reputation aren't [and shouldn't be] the main thing here, but I thought I'd bring this up.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is only correct for the original trilogy.

For all other sites, the beta badge is calculated differently -- primarily by # of questions or answers you provided in the beta time frame.

Comment: Ohh, I assumed the badges were the same throughout all the Q/A sites associated with Stack Exchange. =/. Oops.